# Redirect and Pass Celery Task Data with Django

Tags: django, celery

I would like to build with `django-celery` a web-server that:

1. Accepts data from user on the page `/input/`
2. Starts a `Celery` task to process them
3. Redirects to the page `/wait/`, where user waits until the processing is completed
4. When the task is completed, automatically redirects to the page `/result/`

Currently I got stuck with the code (simplified):

`views.py`:

```
def input(request):
    # Read form data to 'parameters'
    task = process_user_input.delay(parameters)
    response = HttpResponseRedirect("/wait")
    response.session['task'] = task
    return response

def wait(request):
    task = request.session.get('task', None)
    while task.state not in ('SUCCESS', 'FAILURE'):
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/result")

def result(request):
    #
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^input/$', views.input, name = 'input'),
    url(r'^wait/$', views.wait, name = 'wait'),
    url(r'^result/$', views.result, name = 'result'),
)
```

This, however, does not work, as `'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'session'`. I also tried to use `render` function, but it only loads corresponding template without calling the view function.

Can someone help me to fix the code so that it fulfils my goal?

Comment: how could you pass the result of the middle processing? I am also stuck in the similar situation. input -> POST -> wait -> processing -> result. Your answer is helpful but it doesn't show how I can use the result of celery task when redirecting to the result page.

Comment: This is a simplified version of the code. In reality, you should of course save the results in the database (e.g., MySQL; `celery` will do this for you with the session object), pass the session id while redirecting (e.g., `return redirect('some-view-name', id=1234`; alternatively, you can use cookies for this), and extract the required information from the database in the results view.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use database or file as a medium.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I came to conclusion I came to conclusion that the required functionality is not provided by `django`, as one cannot cannot render pages asynchronously (and, as a result, cannot render and redirect at the same time). Therefore, I decided to get rid of the `/wait/` page. My `views.py` now looks like this:

```
from my_app.forms import InputForm
from mysite.tasks import process_user_input

def input(request):
    form = InputForm()
    # Read form data to 'parameters'
    task = process_user_input.delay(parameters)
    while task.state not in ('SUCCESS', 'FAILURE'):
        time.sleep(0.1)
    if task.failed():
        # Insert error message and return to the input form
        render(request, 'my_app/input.html', {'form': form})
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/result")

def result(request):
    #
```

The waiting message I had to implement using `Javascript` with `jQuery` in `input.html`:

```
<div id="form_container">
    <!--The form (with id="input_form") is here-->
</div>
<div id="hidden_section" style="display: none;">
    <!--The please-wait-message is here-->
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#input_form").submit(function () {
        $("#form_container").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#hidden_section").attr("style", "display: block");
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

As a result, after submitting the form, a user remains on the `/input/` page, but is seeing the please-wait-message until the task is completed or an error occurs.